# Keep heading contents always visible in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, visibility

How can you keep a heading's main content always visible in org-mode? 
Perhaps a property that can be set, so that `S-tab` never collapses it? (Not keeping the children's contents visible, unless they are also set the same way, not impacting e.g. narrowing etc.)

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such property: a heading can always be folded.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in `which-function-mode` normally displays the name of the function the point is currently in for languages like C and Python.  But in `org-mode` it treats the current headline as the "function" name to display.

Turn it on temporarily with `M-x which-function-mode` or permanently  for all `org-mode` files with `(add-to-hook 'org-mode-hook #'which-function-mode)` in your `.emacs`.

By default this displays the name in the `mode-line` at the bottom of the buffer.  I find it gets a little crowded down there, so I add it and the buffer name to the header instead:

```
(defun header-buffer-name ()
  (let (
        (props (if (powerline-selected-window-active)
                   '(:box "grey80" :background "grey50" :foreground "black")
                 '(:box "grey80" )))
        )
    (propertize (buffer-name) 'font-lock-face props)
    ))

(defun header-function-name ()
  (let (
        (props (if (powerline-selected-window-active)
                   '(:box "Gold1" :background "goldenrod" :foreground "black")
                 '(:box "Gold1" )))
        (func (when which-function-mode (which-function)))
        )
    (if func
        (propertize (which-function) 'font-lock-face props) "")
    ))

(setq-default header-line-format
              '(:eval
                (list
                 (header-buffer-name)
                 " "
                 (header-function-name)
                 )))
```

[EDIT] Here `(powerline-selected-window-active)` is an external function. You can find several implementations in [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PowerLine), or simply replace it with nil.

Comment: I'm upvoting this since it's actually incredibly useful (perhaps you or I can ask it as a separate question and mark it as solved there). Sadly however, I don't think it actually answers my intended question here — which is about visibility of code folding!